# How can I safely traverse a template linked list in which every node is also a template?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a very basic hash table for an assignment--at this point, it's more of a linked list. I'm having a lot of trouble safely traversing this linked list (checking for null values, etc.) without encountering errors due to the fact that both the hash table class, MyHashTable, and the hash entry struct, MyHashEntry, are templates. At this point, every conditional is throwing an error. I've posted a snippet of my code below. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

```
template<class K, class V>
bool MyHashTable<K, V>::insert(K key, V value)
{
    MyHashEntry<K, V>* temp;
    // table is a private member of class MyHashTable. Its type is MyHashEntry<K, V>**
    // I believe it acts as a pointer to the pointer of the first entry.
    if (table == NULL)
    {
        table = new MyHashEntry<K, V>*;
        *table = new MyHashEntry<K, V>;
    }
        
    temp = *table;
    // Every struct consists of just K key, V value, and MyHashEntry<K, V>* next
    while (temp->key != NULL && temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (temp->key == NULL)
    {
        temp->key = key;
        temp->value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = new MyHashEntry<K, V>;
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->key = key;
        temp->value = value;
    }
    //count and numOfBuckets are also private member variables of MyHashTable
    count++;
    if (count > numOfBuckets)
    {
        numOfBuckets = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors that you’re getting

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Are you shooting for a linear probing hash table or a basic collision-list table ? The allocation of the table itself looks incredibly odd to me. The latter (collision lists) is easier, imho, but that's a long way off from what I'm seeing here.

Comment: Does the code work without templates (if you replace them by the types you pass in)?

Comment: Sometimes it’s easier to start out not using templates. Get the code to work, then generalize it.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.